# call a simulink model using the model name as funcion caller

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am doing archeology of some old Matlab scripts and have found a notation that I did not know it existed:

if you have a simulink MDL file named my_model.mdl, with a single input port and a single output port, then

```
load_system('my_model.mdl')

my_model([],[],[],'compile');
y = my_model(0,0,0,1)
my_model([],[],[],'term');

close_system('my_model.mdl');
```

will give you a result on "y", some sort of evaluation of the simulink model as an input/output function. However I am not able to find documentation about this way of calling simulink models, what the parameters are and so. Does somebody knows where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found it the help page is 
http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/simulink/slref/model_cmd.html